# Function to evaluate which rows are not null and return an INT

Tags: sql-server, binary, int

I am trying to calculate a Numeric Value for if rows checked in SQL Server.  I have done this before on the client side using .NET code.  I am trying to do this within a SQL Server script as the user based came me a excel spread sheet looking like the Input Table.

Days of the Week Example

```
Sun = 1
Mon = 2
Tue = 4
Wed = 8
Thr = 16
Fri = 32
Sat = 64
```

Input Table

```
SYSID SUN MON TUE WED THR FRI SAT
----- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
  1    0   0   1   0   1   0   0
  2    1   1   1   1   1   1   1
  3    0   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

Desired Result

```
SYSID DayOfWeek
----- ---------
  1      20
  2      127
  3      68
```

Without writing 128 Case Statements Or writing the values to another table and doing a SUM function...I am thinking a function where I pass in the values of the 7 fields and it add them together and return the value.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where "which rows are not null" fits into this question.  I see no null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, something like this might work:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN SUN=1 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END)
    +  (CASE WHEN MON=1 THEN 2  ELSE 0 END)
    +  (CASE WHEN TUE=1 THEN 4  ELSE 0 END)
    +  (CASE WHEN WED=1 THEN 8  ELSE 0 END)
    +  (CASE WHEN THU=1 THEN 16 ELSE 0 END)
    +  (CASE WHEN FRI=1 THEN 32 ELSE 0 END)
    +  (CASE WHEN SAT=1 THEN 64 ELSE 0 END)
    AS DayOfWeek
FROM InputTable
```

Comment: Thanks...much easier than I thought.